# View RDLC using MVC with parameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Can you help me?

I'm new in creating MVC application

Is it possible to view RDLC report in mvc using aspx? If yes...
How can I view that report using parameters in mvc?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rdlc-integration-in-mvc-application-report-display-using-iframe/

Comment: There is a nuget package also available just search for it and implement

Comment: but I used stored procedure to get the data using parameters